# Como melhorar a segurança do asp.net Membership?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Tem como proteger aquele cookie que fica evidente ao fazer login em um site que usa o asp.net membership ? Sei que basta copiar ele pra que "clone" a sessão de login e desse modo fica muito vulnerável principalmente a ataques man in the middle .

A única solução é usar SSL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para qualquer Cookie que você precise criar, independentemente de linguagem/plataforma, é altamente recomendável que seja definida a flag **HttpOnly** [que te ajuda a previnir manipulações do seu Cookie através de JavaScript, e consequentemente ataques XSS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533046.aspx), além da flag **Secure**, que a própria [W3C](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109) padronizou como uma forma de evitar que sejam aceitas requisições com Cookies através de canais inseguros.

De fato, se alguém conseguir de alguma forma gerar o conteúdo exato do seu Cookie de autenticação, ele pode muito bem alterar o Cookie no browser e utilizá-lo. Mas temos que considerar que o próprio Asp.Net já cuida bem da parte de encriptar seus Cookies através da configuração do [machineKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx), o que torna essa prática bem improvável.

Por outro lado, o usuário nem precisaria gerar o conteúdo se for facilitado o roubo dessas informações. Com a flag HttpOnly, você impede que scripts maliciosos em JavaScript consigam ler seus Cookies e a flag Secure garante que a aplicação só irá entender o conteúdo se o mesmo estiver trafegando por SSL, que é obrigatório hoje em dia para evitar tráfego de informações em texto puro, que poderiam ser facilmente lidas por ataques man-in-the-middle.

Em Asp.Net, as configurações podem ser feitas através de configurações no Web.config com o elemento [httpCookies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms228262(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

Para qualquer Cookie, você consegue setar programaticamente:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
myCookie.HttpOnly = true;
Response.AppendCookie(myCookie);
```

Especificamente no caso do Cookie de autenticação, é possível forçar a flag secure no elemento [**forms**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.requiressl.aspx):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="true" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Diego , tentei usar o requireSSL e recebi o seguinte erro "
O aplicativo está configurado para emitir cookies seguros. Esses cookies requerem que o navegador emita a solicitação sobre SSL (protocolo https). No entanto, a solicitação atual não é sobre SSL. ", vc sabe me dizer como implemento o SSL ?

Comment: @DiegoValadares você precisa contratar um certificado SSL e configurá-lo no seu servidor web para que ele possa servir as respostas como https. Para ambientes de desenvolvimento, você consegue instalar certificados próprios apenas para testar a sua instalação. No IIS existe uma configuração específica para [self-signed certificates](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates)